# What is difference between E signature (Electronic Signature) and Digital Signature?

Tags: digital-signature, pki

I would like to understand difference between E Signature (Electronic Signature) and Digital Signature ? Can we replace digital signature with e signature ? what is benefit to use e signature over digital signature ?

Answer (score 1):

[This link](https://www.assuresign.com/electronic-signatures-vs-digital-signatures/) answers all of your questions stated above. Most importantly:

> Electronic signature is not the same as a digital signature, even though many use the two terms interchangeably. Digital signatures embed a unique digital “fingerprint” into documents and the signer is required to possess a certificate-based digital ID (a digital certificate) in order to link the signer and document. Digital certificates are digital forms of identification; you can compare it to the physical forms of ID, such as a driver’s license or a passport.
>   
>   
>   Electronic signature is the most prevalent method of executing agreements and making purchases because reputable e-sign providers are held accountable by the eSign Act of 2000 and the Uniform Electronic Transactions Act (UETA), which indicates high levels of security while still maintaining signer convenience; better put, AssureSign adheres to the gold standard of e-sign laws

Comment: So if I understand it correctly, "electronic signature" doesn't need to be made by the signer's _personal_ key, and doesn't need to be cryptographic at all (it might even be a database entry claiming "this document was signed by X").